# Working with larger that 2 billion elements big-arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bigdata, limit

I am constantly having to work with large arrays in Java, constantly testing the ~2B elements limitation.

Is there a convenient way to work with arrays of larger size? The list of operations I need:

- create a new array;
- set/get *i-th* element;
- extend the array by allocating a new one of larger size and copying contents of the old array;
- copying contents of another array (rather small << 2B) to the array.

**P.S.** It seems that this problem has been thinked over by a number of engineers. Nice article with references could be found at: https://www.nayuki.io/page/large-arrays-proposal-for-java

Comment: You could try to go with 2D array like int[2][1B] instead of int[2B] or use `List`

Comment: Try fastutil library.

Comment: @Hitobat Thanks for the reference. It's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Hitobat Ported my code to the *fastutil library* and it works like a charm! I wish you convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need to externalise it to an SQL/NoSQL database.

Comment: @Bohemian That will introduce a dramatical drop in performance. I switched to using primitive byte arrays for the exact reason of squeezing every drop of speed from a processor and it still stays the number one priority.

Comment: I've converted the comment as requested @DenisKulagin, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library. I use it mainly for the space-efficient Java collections (using primitive arrays internally), but there's also a section about [Big data structures](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/#big) for collections with `> 2^31` elements.